# What is the C# "checked" keyword for?

Tags: c#

I just came across this keyword for the first time.  What does it do, and when should it be used?

```
int multiply(int i, int j)
{
    return checked(i * j);
}
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Eric Lippert has a two-part blog post "What is the unchecked keyword good for?": [Part 1](http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/09/what-is-the-unchecked-keyword-good-for-part-one/#more-2601) -- [Part 2](http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/13/what-is-the-unchecked-keyword-good-for-part-two/#more-2603)

---

["Checked"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) is a block keyword that enables arithmetic overflow checking.  Normally, if an integer operation exceeds the maximum or minimum value that the type can handle, the operation proceeds anyway, and the result just cycles like an odometer.  So, for example:

```
byte b = byte.MaxValue;
Console.WriteLine(b);       // 255  (11111111)
Console.WriteLine(++b);     // 0    (00000000)
```

Placing this snippet in a `checked` block prevents the overflow, and instead the runtime throws an [`OverflowException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.overflowexception):

```
checked
{
    byte b = byte.MaxValue;
    Console.WriteLine(b);               // b=255
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(++b);
    }
    catch (OverflowException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);   // "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow." 
                                        // b = 255
    }
}
```

And since there's a compiler option [`/checked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language), which turns compiler checking on by default, there is also the [`unchecked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked) keyword which prevents overflow checking.

---

As far as usage, overflow checking should be used sparingly, [as is true of exception handling in general](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/exceptions-and-performance).  To check for an overflow at runtime, it's significantly faster (like, an order of magnitude) to do a simple check, rather than to turn on overflow checking:

```
int multiply(int i, int j)
{ 
    if ((long)i * (long)j > int.MaxValue)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("overflow");
    return i*j;
}
```

You can do this even for Int64/long, using [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger) (this can be still at least an order of magnitude faster than using `checked`):

```
long multiply(long i, long j)
{ 
    if (new System.Numerics.BigInteger(i) + j > long.MaxValue)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("overflow");
    return i*j;
}
```

---

There's also a good [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7776/Arithmetic-Overflow-Checking-using-checked-uncheck) article on this that explains some caveats (eg, the overflow check only applies to the immediate code block, not to any function calls inside the block).

Comment: Are you sure it's actually faster though? Becase the benchmarks I am running seem to disagree

Comment: I wrote this code
https://dotnetfiddle.net/P6brPu
on my local machine on release build and checked seems to always be faster