# Why am I getting a result even though int value exceeds the limit?

Tags: c#

This is just a basic sum method.

```
public int Sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

If I call the function as below

```
int result = Sum(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);
```

Why am I gettin ‘-2’ in the result variable even though there is an overflow. Shouldn't I get a stackoverflow exception?

Comment: Not a stack overflow, but an [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Comment: Because that's what checked code does. It overflows. Why would you expect a stack overflow? This doesn't have anything to do with exceeding the stack.

Comment: And here's another question which addresses how to prevent this: [What is the C# "checked" keyword for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709495/what-is-the-c-sharp-checked-keyword-for)

Comment: Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#arithmetic-overflow-and-division-by-zero "In an unchecked context, the result is truncated by discarding any high-order bits that don't fit in the destination type." (and shows example similar to this question)